# Sonar - Xunit file is not parsed by sonar-runner

Tags: python, report, sonarqube, nosetests, xunit

I have a strange issue with Sonar-Runner on a Python project.
Here is my conf:
SonarQube : 5.1.2
Sonar Runner : 2.4
Python Plugin : 1.5

I have un simple Python project "PyTest" :

- tests
- reports
- pgm.py
- VO.py

I use nose (v1.3.7) to generate coverage and xunit files with this command:

```
nostetests --with-coverage --cover-xml --cover-inclusive --with-xunit --xunit-file=reports/xunit.xml --cover-xml-file=reports/cover.xml
```

I have provisionning Sonar with the "pytestkey" and here is my sonar-project.properties

```
sonar.projectKey=pytestkey
sonar.projectName=PyTest
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.sources=.
sonar.tests=tests
sonar.language=py
sonar.exclusions=tests/*

sonar.python.xunit.reportPath=reports/xunit.xml
sonar.python.coverage.reportPath=reports/cover.xml
sonar.python.codeCoveragePlugin=cobertura
```

When I run everything is find excepted the xunit.xml file is never parsed...

Log:

```
INFO - Sensor PythonXUnitSensor
DEBUG - Using pattern 'reports/xunit.xml' to find reports
INFO - Sensor PythonXUnitSensor (done) | time 19ms
INFO - Sensor PythonCoverageSensor
DEBUG - Using pattern 'reports/cover.xml' to find reports
INFO - Parsing report '/home/bsantus/workspace/PyTest/reports/cover.xml'
DEBUG - Saving coverage measures for file 'pgm.py'
DEBUG - Saving coverage measures for file 'VO.py'
DEBUG - Parsing integration test coverage reports
DEBUG - Using pattern 'coverage-reports/it-coverage-*.xml' to find reports
DEBUG - Parsing overall test coverage reports
DEBUG - Using pattern 'coverage-reports/overall-coverage-*.xml' to find reports
INFO - Sensor PythonCoverageSensor (done) | time 65ms
```

Any ideas why the xunit.xml file is not used?

Thanks for all

Comment: Why do you think your report is not used? What do you see in SonarQube?

Comment: In fact, i notice that meta informations are used (number of tests, number of succes, numbers of fails) but their is no drilldown available in Sonar that allow me to browse tests files and tests results. After reading more about Sonar-runner, i think that Sonar is not able to link tests results with source files where are these tests.

Answer (score 0):

Your report is parsed, but the default behavior of version 1.5 of the Python plugin is to only record project-level metrics.
You should try to add the following line to your sonar-project.properties:

```
sonar.python.xunit.skipDetails=false
```

Comment: after adding this property

Processing report '/srv/jenkins/workspace/Platform_Communique_Pull_Requests_Sonar/app/nosetests.xml'
DEBUG: Trying to find a SonarQube resource for 'app.test.unit.data_sources.test_mysql.MysqlTester'...
DEBUG: Using the key 'app/test/unit/data_sources/test_mysql/MysqlTester.py' to lookup the resource in SonarQube
DEBUG: Using the key 'app/test/unit/data_sources/test_mysql.py' to lookup the resource in SonarQube
DEBUG: ... cannot find the resource for 'app.test.unit.data_sources.test_mysql.MysqlTester', drilling down to the details of this test wont be possible